# Node.js and socket.io thousands of unsuccessful connection attempts

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

Good evening SO-community, I tried really hard to fix this issue but I think I'll need your wisdom because I really don't know what's the matter here. I have a node.js server which is serving an index.html via express. I am currently starting to use socket.io.

**This is the code on my client side:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", startGame);


function startGame() {
    var socket = io();  console.log("Sending request to server");
    socket.emit('connectToTable', {tableID: 1});      

socket.on('successfulConnection', function(msg){
          alert(msg);
        }); }

});
```

**This is the code on my server side:**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var express = require('express');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log("There is someone knocking on the door")
  socket.on('connectToTable', function(socket){
    console.log("Received player request")
    var player = new Player(socket.id);
    socket.emit('successfulConnection', "The connection to the server has been successful");
  });
});

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

On my console on the server I see that "There is someone knocking on the door" gets printed hundreds or thousands of times per second which leads to a CPU load of 100%. At the same time I can see on the client-side (in Chrome) that hundreds of xhr polls are being made.

[image: Connections in Chrome]

I really can't figure out why the connection is not established after the first connection attempt and retried sooo often. Furthermore I don't even really understand why it is even using xhr polling instead of websockets.

Help would be very highly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Is there any chance this is being caused by the lack of semi-colons at the end of the console.log() lines on the server-side?

Comment: Also, I'd remove the `new Player` line as a test to see if that could be causing an exception inside of that event.

Comment: @Jordan: Unfortunately not. I just tried it and I haven't had this console.log in the code before. Furthermore modern JS shouldn't care about that too much anyway. But good idea. I am so curious what might cause this problem.. Really don't know anymore. I wonder if it might have something to do with the static serving of the root folder via express...

EDIT: Removing it didn't help. I don't get any errors btw.

Comment: socket.io uses xhr requests to set up the connection, so I don't believe the connection is getting set up successfully.  That said, I don't see the error either.  I'll stare at it a bit longer then give up and wait for someone smarter to solve the problem.

Comment: Do you really write Javascript code with four statements on one line and large amounts of horizontal scrolling needed to view your code?

Comment: Try temporarily removing the `socket.emit('connectToTable', {tableID: 1});` in the client.  You are trying to `socket.emit()` BEFORE the connection has been established.  I'm wondering if that is messing things up.  Also, what version of socket.io are you using and do you have the same version of socket.io on client and server?

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry, the formatting seems to have been messed up a little. The mistake really was that the versions didn't match. Thank you so much for your help as well (ElíasMarNev suggsted that a little earlier though so I marked his answer a correct). I am so grateful that people like you are here who help when help is needed.

Comment: When you see messed up formatting, why don't you fix it?  There's an "edit" link so you can fix it to be right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the same version of socket.io, on the client and on the server (I have had the same problem 5 days ago), check on console with:

> npm list socket.io

the version of the server and look if you use the same version on the client, on index.html like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
```

You can get the url from here:

[Versions of socket.io](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io)

Regards

Comment: Moreover, I resolved the problem used that:   var socket = io.connect('ws://yourDomain:port/', {transports: ['websocket']});  (On openshift I need to use the port 8000 for http and 8443 for https).

Comment: Thank you so much. I would have never found that out. Yeah, that happens when you install it on node via npm but copy the line on the frontend from the (old) tutorial code.